# ctrl + z, ctrl + y not working in slate.js editor

Tags: javascript, frontend, editor, slate, slate-react

`ctrl z` not working in my `slateJs` editor, but it is working fine in [slate example](https://www.slatejs.org/examples/richtext)

```
    <Slate editor={editor} value={initialValue}>
      <Editable
        renderElement={renderElement}
        renderLeaf={renderLeaf}
        ...
        ...
        onKeyDown = {()=> {
          console.log('key pressed')
        }
      </Editable>
    </Slate>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use withHistory like the source of the example you have given: https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/blob/main/site/examples/richtext.tsx#L28
for default undo and redo behaviour